# Play frame RawSql how can I getTotalPage

Tags: java, web-applications, playframework, playframework-2.2

I use Play 2.2.6. I want to get 'getTotalPageCount' with `RawSql`, but 
I always get one page record. 
Here is the code:

```
   String sql = "select "
            + "a.id as id ,"
            + "b.name as computerType ,"
            + "a.buy_time as buyTime ,"
            + "a.user_name as userName, "
            + "a.if_use as ifUse from computer a left join computer_type b on a.computer_type = b.code where 1=1 ";

    if(StringUtil.StringNoEmpty(vo.userName)){
        sql += " and a.user_name like '%"+vo.userName+"%'";
    }

    if(StringUtil.StringNoEmpty(vo.computerType)){
        sql += " and a.computer_type = '"+vo.computerType+"'";
    }
    if(null!=vo.startTime){         
        String startTime = DateUtil.formate.format(vo.startTime);
        sql += " and a.buy_time >= '"+startTime+"'";
    }

    if(null!=vo.endTime){
        String endTime = DateUtil.formate.format(vo.endTime);
        sql += " and a.buy_time <= '"+endTime+"'";
    }

    if(StringUtil.StringNoEmpty(vo.ifUse)){
        if("on".equals(vo.ifUse)){
            sql += " and a.if_use ='1' ";
        }else if("off".equals(vo.ifUse)){
            sql += " and a.if_use = '0'";
        }
    }

    RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql).create();

    Query<ResultComputer> query = Ebean.find(ResultComputer.class).order("id");
    query.setRawSql(rawSql);

    Page<ResultComputer> page = query.findPagingList(10).setFetchAhead(false).getPage(0);
    Logger.debug(page.getTotalPageCount()+""); // result  1.
```

but my  database have one thousand records. I think "page.getTotalPageCount()" should be 100 page record . Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getTotalPageCount();
```

Return the total number of pages.Since you have given `getPage(0)`, it returns 1. [`getPage(0)`-Return the page for a given page position (starting at 0)]. If you want total page count: perform `getTotalPageCount();` on `pagingList` fetched.